# Iterating over std::map in PHP with SWIG

Tags: php, c++, dictionary, swig, language-binding

I am using SWIG to wrap a function that returns an `std::map` in PHP.

In the PHP code, I need to iterate over the elements of the map.

Thw SWIG library provides support for `std::map` with the `std_map.i` interface file, but only the following methods are wrapped:

```
 clear()
 del($key)
 get($key)
 has_key($key)
 is_empty()
 set($key, $x)
 size()
```

How can I iterate over the elements of the map? Would I need to extend the `std_map.i` file with some sort of wrappers for iterators and `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: Challenge accepted. The "right" thing to do is implement PHP's [iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) but it looks like that might be a bit tricky. I'll have a think

Answer (score 1):

As @awoodland said you will have to implement the iterator interface.

Here is another question on stackoverflow.  Although it is java it can give you a better idea of what you are looking for:

[No iterator for Java when using SWIG with C++'s std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465856/no-iterator-for-java-when-using-swig-with-c-and-stdmap)